# Buck input decoupling capacitance and efficiency

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck, resonance

I'm working on an high frequency buck (>10 MHz) and there's a problem with the input decoupling capacitance, the one used to filter battery harmonics and have a more stable voltage with less ripple.
In our testbench we have an ideal voltage source and two RL series which represents PCB trace before and after capacitor. Bondings wires are modeled as RL and they connect HS drain to battery.
It's a multiphase design with n-n phases.

I have noticed that by using certain values of capacitance efficiency decreases and this happens when red box RLC has resonance frequency similar to buck switching frequency (total Fsw and not the half fsw of each phase)
Seems obvious to avoid resonance so I've used a bigger capacitor and got an higher efficiency.
The problem is that I still lose around 4 % of efficiency compared to eff peak: what happens is that Vbatt provides x ampere but around 5% goes to charge the damping capacitor (or whatever).
Capacitor is basically always charged at regime.
Initial simulations were done without ESR but even with ESR things don't really change and if you think power loss related to a capacitor you think about ESR and not the capacitor itself.
I can reach the efficiency peak by using a really small capacitor (47 nF compared to 4.7 uF) but filtering action is really bland.
Another problem of using 47 nF is that if i account real capacitor tolerance and a PCB trace just 0.5 mm longer I refall into resonance/switching frequency.
I cannot design things around a +- 20 % capacitor and PCB parasitic inductance so I must use a big capacitor to avoid risky zone.

I've done some literature research and at my fsw small caps are used (< 10 nF) and only one work mentions this problem suggesting to avoid fres=fsw.
The problem is a bit weird because with a small Cdamp I have worse input voltage so I expected more voltage overshot during buck switching activity and higher switching losses.
Since it's a master thesis I'm more interested to know your opinion about this resonance effect and not a link to a ultra low tolerance capacitor. The impact of this problem is pretty big (we aren't talking of a +-0.01% efficiency) so it must be explained in a convincing way.

[image]

Comment: Please post your buck input voltage waveform (ripple). What’s your max input current? What’s the max voltage over/undershoot you can allow for 0-100 or 100-0 % load step?

Comment: In decoupling for high speed logic, it has become common to use a hierarchy of decoupling; different circuits with different self-resonant freqs to cover different ranges of frequency. Increasing Cdamp has presumably brought its resonance below Fsw : perhaps you need an additional network with a *smaller* Cdamp and resonance above Fsw?